# Simple utility to rip ISO's on Windows (7)

Tags: windows-7, windows, ripping, iso-image

I'm after a really simple utility to rip ISO's from CD's and DVD's on Windows 7.

Ideally it would be very small, free and have no spammy-ness to it (no advers, no nags etc). A simple right click of the DVD drive then *convert to ISO*...

Any recommendations?..

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try [isobuster](http://www.isobuster.com/) (can read discs with errors) or [LC IsoCreator](http://www.softpedia.com/get/CD-DVD-Tools/CD-DVD-Rip-Other-Tools/LC-ISO-Creator.shtml) (just 52Kb)

Comment: I like the basicness of LC ISOCreator. Thanks

Comment: +1 for LC IsoCreator. I only need to perform one function (create ISOs from disk) and this tool does exactly that. Love the minimalism!

Comment: LC IsoCreator link is dead and taken over by a domain squatter.

Comment: @user26398 Link updated.

Comment: The LC ISOCreator link installs a bunch of adware, BEWARE

Comment: The current LC IsoCreator link (softpedia) has no adware.

Comment: LCISOCreator seems mostly legit: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/5b5713c3cc73a2c4363433fb86bd028133f1062b1e10ec4d8b88ef4d1776d8f2/details

Answer (score 19):

http://www.imgburn.com/

Free (no cost), and simple, simple to use.

Comment: imgburn is fantastic!

Comment: Beware the *2* screens of adware opt-out on the installer, though. Choose "Custom Install" and uncheck the box in both instances.

Comment: Beware, beware, extreme adware. Product works ok though.

Answer (score 3):

ISO Recorder is also a nice simple tool, and free also.

http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm