# ISO file is not bootable to be used in a virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

I'm trying to install `Windows server 2008 R2` using a virtual machine (testing with both vmware and virtualbox).
I have the windows DVD and I am able to boot from it.
my problem is that I am trying to install the `Windows Server` on a virtual machine on a my PC which doesn't have a `DVD-Drive`.

so I created an `.iso` file from my DVD but both virtual machines are not recognizing my `.iso` file as bootable, what can I do ?

**EDIT:**
I created the `ISO` using `Ultra ISO` and I am working on windows 8.1.

Comment: How have you created the ISO?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple utility to rip ISO's on Windows (7)](http://superuser.com/questions/166996/simple-utility-to-rip-isos-on-windows-7)

Comment: @kobaltz: I don't see how this can be a duplicate, my problem is not in creating the `ISO` I already have it.
but the the ISO is not working, do you this it is because of using the wrong tool ?

Comment: I'm thinking that it is either corrupted or not built correctly. Try to use the other software suggested in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

For VMWare, you can try to install from the Disk directly, but choosing to install from a physical drive. and choose (/dev/cdrom).

UPDATE: Since you are missing a physical drive, you could try ripping the iso using some other software or make sure that you have unchecked anything of the flags on the disk.

You could also copy the contents on a pen drive and then make the pen dirve bootable using BOOTREC.EXE. I have never tried that with 2008 R2, but I have done that with Win7 Ultimate. It should be the same drill.

Comment: i think the problem is that the OP does not have a physical drive for use by the host

Comment: and I have the same issue with virtual box as well